# What is a "Diophantine number"?

Tags: number-theory

In this phrase, excerpted from [Terry Tao's blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/08/12/avila-bhargava-hairer-mirzakhani/),

> "$\alpha$ being ... very far from rational (a Diophantine number), ..."

what is a "Diophantine number"? He contrasts it with a [Liouville number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number).
Thanks!

Comment: I think [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460929/diophantine-number-has-full-measure-but-is-meager) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @recursiverecursion: Yes!---Thank you!