# Showing a set which is not diophantine contains a thick subset

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show the set X = {x ∈ [0, 1] : x is not diophantine} contains a thick subset of [0, 1].

A real number x is said to be Diophatine if for every ε > 0, there exists a constant c<sub>ε</sub> such that |x - y| ≥ c<sub>ε</sub>/(|q|<sup>2+ε</sup>) where y = a/q is a rational number.

So for x not diophantine, we have |x - y| < c<sub>ε</sub>/(|q|<sup>2+ε</sup>) but i don't know how to use that to show X has a thick subset of [0,1]

any hints?

Comment: What do you mean by "thick"?  Full measure?  Dense $G_\delta$?

Comment: by thick, I mean countable intersection of open-dense sets.

Comment: What justifies your claim "Diophantine -> for every ε > 0, ...". Is it a known theorem?

Comment: yeah, that's given

Comment: @Yeti: Can you give a reference or link?

Comment: @quasi here you go, [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation]

Comment: @Yeti: Thanks for the link, but that page only mentions Diophantine approximation. Nowhere on that page is the term "Diophantine set" mentioned. If there is a connection between those two concepts, please give a link or reference, or state a named theorem.

Comment: @quasi I don't have anything else. Also I must have made a mistake earlier, a real number is said to be Diophantine, not a set. I just corrected it above. My apologies.

Comment: @yeti: This link might be relevant:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460929/diophantine-number-has-full-measure-but-is-meager

Comment: @quasi That is helpful! Thank you.